# Is unsweetened tea 'stronger' than sweetened tea

Tags: perception

I feel that if I have unsweetened tea, it has a stronger hit. i.e. it is more stimulating than a similar cup of tea in which some sugar has been added. I can say the same about coffee.

Is it just me or is it something which is commonly perceived?

Is there a biochemical basis for this feeling or is it psychological due to the slight bitter taste?

Comment: my money is on and entirely biochemical and physical, tastebud-reason.